# How do you differentiate an uncertainty function?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, differentiation

The uncerainty of an ensemble of particles can be represented as (from the Schrodinger uncertainty relation):

$g(t) = (\langle p^2\rangle(t)-(\langle p\rangle(t))^2)(\langle q^2\rangle(t)-(\langle q\rangle(t))^2)-(\langle pq\rangle(t)-\langle p\rangle(t)\langle q\rangle(t))$

How do you differentiate this wrt time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all $\langle \cdots \rangle$ are scalar functions of $t$, you will have to differentiate the expression with the usual differentiation rules. How this looks in detail will depend on your problem at hand, i.e. the form of the $\langle \cdots \rangle$ expressions.

Comment: would <pq> differentiate to <pq'+p'q> or <pq'>+<p'q> ?

Comment: Since $p$ and $q$ are operators, it is a good idea to first evaluate $\langle pq\rangle$ as a function of $t$ and only then differentiate. Otherwise, just write down the expression for the expectation value, differentiate and see what you get.

Comment: the paper I'm looking at just states the differentiated function without evaluating the operators: http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4966917 see equation 5

Comment: It might be easiest to see if you write out the expectation values as e.g. $\langle\psi | p^2 |\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi | p |\psi\rangle^2$. The derivative of the former is $\langle\psi| 2p\dot{p}|\psi\rangle$, since $|\psi\rangle$ does not depend on $t$, the latter becomes $2 \langle \psi|p|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|\dot{p}|\psi\rangle$.